# filtering in c# using sql server as database

Tags: c#

filtering in c# using sql server as database

for example choosing first what to filter in the combobox by choosing student number and in the textfield entering 1001 ...den only 1001 will appear in the datagrid...

we are using ssql server

Comment: I see this is a real question.

Comment: IS this question the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243294/datagrid-filter-in-c-using-sql-server Please be more clear what is the problem the sql query ot the binding with the grid ?

Comment: yeah like that? we try to code it... if we enter 1001 it will appear 1001 in the datagrid but the thing is the other data are still there in the datagrid

Answer (score 2):

With a vague question like this I can only point you into the direction of LINQ to SQL  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an old way of doing this, It is for an idea, what steps are involved. It will work fine but I will advise to look into Entity Framework / Datasets. Table Adapters

---

```
            // Read from file
            FileStream fs;
            fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);           

            // Conver to binary
            byte[] binaryData = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(binaryData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            fs.Close();


            // insert into DB
            string connstr = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestImage;
                Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            conn.Open();

            string query = "insert into test_table(binaryCoulumn) values(" + binaryData + "+)";

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Binary;
            parameter.ParameterName = "binaryCoulumn";
            parameter.Value = binaryData;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         

            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
```

---

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

here is her code why malou17 has an error
malou17 code

> > > when malou17 runs the program...and filter 1001 in student number...it will appear in the datagrid but the old data are still there..for example 1002 is still in the datagrid

}

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbofilter.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            string sql;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server= " + Environment.MachineName.ToString() + @"\; Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security = true";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            ds1 = DBConn.getStudentDetails("sp_RetrieveSTUDNO");
            sql = "Select * from Test where STUDNO like '" + txtvalue.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds1);

            dbgStudentDetails.DataSource = ds1;
            dbgStudentDetails.DataMember = ds1.Tables[0].TableName;
            dbgStudentDetails.Refresh();

        }
        else if (cbofilter.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            //string sql;
            //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            //conn.ConnectionString = "Server= " + Environment.MachineName.ToString() + @"\; Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security = true";

            //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            //ds1 = DBConn.getStudentDetails("sp_RetrieveSTUDNO");
            //sql = "Select * from Test where Name like '" + txtvalue.Text + "'";
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            //da.Fill(ds1);

           // dbgStudentDetails.DataSource = ds1;
            //dbgStudentDetails.DataMember = ds1.Tables[0].TableName;
            //ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Studno = + txtvalue.text + "; 
            dbgStudentDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dbgStudentDetails.Refresh();

        }
```